# When $a+b=2\sqrt{E}$, does that imply that $a=b=\sqrt{E}$?

Tags: geometry, logic

As the title says. a,b,E are arbitrary positive numbers. If this is true, how can i prove it?

Comment: Take $E=4,a=1,b=3$.

Comment: Am I missing something?  Why on earth *would* it?  As $\sqrt{E}$ can be pretty much anything this would mean $a + b = 2x \implies a = b$ which is ludicrous. $a = 2\sqrt{E} - b$ so a and be can be any {$(x,y)| x \in (0, 2\sqrt{E}), y = 2\sqrt{E} - x$}.  Is $\sqrt{E}$ supposed to be irrational and a, b rationals or integers or something?  Even then I can't see this making much sense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Plot $y=2\sqrt{E}-x$ for $E>0$ fixed and see which $y>0$ when $x>0$:

[image]

It is clearly not the only solution. Every ordered pair on the segment going from $(0,2\sqrt{E})$ to $(2\sqrt{E},0)$ is a solution.